# align containers uniformly - html/css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please go through the [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/W8R1twQnVD) here

I am having difficulty in arranging `div` containers uniformly when the `a` text is considerably large.

Check the third container in the example. It distorts the overall look and feel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `vertical-align: top;` to `.category`.  See here:

http://www.bootply.com/4RnKOuqejz

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
    .category {
        vertical-align: top;
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 18%;
        /*height: 40%;*/
    }

    .categoryContainer .category img {
        width: 190px;
        height: 150px;
    }

    .categoryContainer .category a {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

        .categoryContainer .category a:hover {
            color: #DC5034;
        }

    .categoryContainer .category .fa-play {
        padding-left: 6px;
        font-size: 8px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #DC5034;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding-right: 8px;
    }

    .categoryContainer .category p {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="categoryContainer" style="width:100%">
                    <div class="category">
                        <div class="imageContainer">
                            <img src="" class="img-responsive">
                            <a class="noHover" href="https://www.google.com/">Property 1</a><i class="fa fa-play"></i>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="category" style="height:40%">
                        <div class="imageContainer">
                            <img src="" class="img-responsive">
                            <a>Property 2</a><i class="fa fa-play"></i>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="category" style="height:40%">
                        <div class="imageContainer">
                            <img src="" class="img-responsive">
                            <a>A very big property name that distorts the uniformity</a><i class="fa fa-play"></i>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="category" style="height:40%">
                        <div class="imageContainer">
                            <img src="" class="img-responsive">
                            <a>Property 4</a><i class="fa fa-play"></i>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="category" style="height:40%">
                        <div class="imageContainer">
                            <img src="" class="img-responsive">
                            <a>Property 5</a><i class="fa fa-play"></i>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="category" style="height:40%">
                        <div class="imageContainer">
                            <img src="" class="img-responsive">
                            <a>Property 6</a><i class="fa fa-play"></i>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="category" style="height:40%">
                        <div class="imageContainer">
                            <img src="" class="img-responsive">
                            <a>Property 7</a><i class="fa fa-play"></i>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="category" style="height:40%">
                        <div class="imageContainer">
                            <img src="" class="img-responsive">
                            <a>Property 8</a><i class="fa fa-play"></i>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: isnt there a different way of doing it?

Comment: @user2281858 That's entirely up to what you actually want to achieve.  The question was very vague, so I went with what might preserve look and feel in my opinion.  What particularly are you wanting to see as a final result?

Comment: @Joesph Markile the answer is good. I am just trying to see if this will work if I have a very big paragraph on it.

Comment: That unfortunately is not certain.  Content is just as important as styling and if your content does not conform to the design, there's a good chance it will break the styling.  If you have absolutely no control over the content the last resort would be to hide the overflow (http://www.bootply.com/Fj4dTXQw4c), but otherwise it'll come down to instructing the end user about good content vs bad content.

Comment: This is great...can ellipsis work on the 3rd line. Say, I have a long para and want to cut it on the 3rd line...will it work?

Comment: Unfortunately it cannot as far as I know.  It's restricted to use with single line text only, which is unfortunate.  That fact really limits the application of `text-overflow`.

Comment: not a problem....i will bind the data accordingly by using substring

Answer (score 1):

If your page is dynamic, then you could limit the number of characters being printed.

But if it's static, then you'll want to either write a shorter title or make the rows with the div's taller.